# How to get all mobile measurements in Android using dart and flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to create an app the get all Device Information as the below link in `git hub`:

https://github.com/MHarooney/All-Device-Information

As I need to get these types of info below images:

[image]

[image]

and those Infos I get it when dialing this code `*#*#4636#*#*`, and I get this screen to access the Phone information as the below Image:

[image]

I searched a lot and can't find plugins give me this information using `flutter` and `dart`

I hope someone could help me to solve this!!

## Edited:

Overall I want to create something like `Open Signal` application that access the mobile network or `sim` network as the below link:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.staircase3.opensignal&gl=NL

Answer (score 1):

Why would you need the measurement of all android devices? Android devices have wide spread of screen sizes instead you can use mediaquery() widget to set multi layout screens instead of inputting raw width and height

Comment: I need to get this infos as to create a database with them and start  making charts and visualization for every user related to the radio network

Comment: You can average these infos with most popular devices with its dimensions on market. Since there are more different sizes yet with only small changes in its dimension from popular ones. I think its better to average results with popular models

Comment: it's not related to device info bro it's related to sim info you can check the second image please I have parameters like MCC, MNC, TAC, CID, PCI, EARFCN, RSRP and RSRQ.... all this parameters is related to sim info, what I need to extract or read those parameters and make a database with them, and make a visualization and create some charts for them as to solve network performence